# RabbitMq consume by priority

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I want to consume messages from RabbitMq queue but only for one `priority`, I have priority declaration for my queue `x-max-priority:10`
and messages with priority

```
Exchange    exchange.fanout
Properties  priority:   10
            content_type:   text/plain
```

And now how can I consume messages only with priority `2`

I have tried like this

```
$channel->basic_consume(
    'priority-queue',
    '',
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    function ($message) {
        /** @var AMQPMessage $message */
        echo $message->getBody();
        echo "\n";
    },
    null,
    new AMQPTable(
        [
            'x-priority' => 2,
        ]
    )
);
```

But I'm getting all messages, and when I use `x-priority => ['I', 2]` but then I'm getting `PRECONDITION_FAILED - invalid arg 'x-priority' for queue 'priority-queue'`

Answer (score 0):

> And now how can I consume messages only with priority 2

the easiest way to do this is to change your routing so that your "priority" messages are sent to a queue where only these messages will arrive.

then you never have to worry about other messages in the queue, and your consumer can be dedicated to any message in this queue... which happen to only be messages of this "priority"

Comment: Now I have such solution, where I have `x` queues and my exchange decide where to put my message. But since there is possibility to keep all messages in one queue I want to try this solution